Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `localhost`,
this is my docker compose
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres-data:

this my schema
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

and this is env
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb?schema=public"
and this is error
Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at localhost, the provided database credentials for myuser are not valid.
Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at localhost.
i try to change user and password but it not ok
this is postgre logs
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```2024-05-06 09:09:04.330 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-05-06 09:09:04.403 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-05-06 09:09:04.403 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-05-06 09:09:04.408 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-05-06 09:09:04.413 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-05-06 04:51:01 UTC
2024-05-06 09:09:04.429 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-05-06 09:14:04.428 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-06 09:14:04.443 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint complete: w


2024-05-06 09:09:04.330 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-05-06 09:09:04.403 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-05-06 09:09:04.403 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-05-06 09:09:04.408 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-05-06 09:09:04.413 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-05-06 04:51:01 UTC
2024-05-06 09:09:04.429 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-05-06 09:14:04.428 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-06 09:14:04.443 UTC [28] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.005 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.016 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/1954EA8, redo lsn=0/1954E70


can you please share your postgres container logs?

Does this answer your question? Connect to another container using Docker compose
